# Extend Directives Scope AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directives, that use the same function, depending on manipulating the view and the data.

```
scope.hide()
scope.show()
...
```

Currently I am writing a service, but services are mostly for data.

Any suggestions? What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: What is the question exactly?  Best solution for what?

Comment: @DavinTryon my guess is that the question is how to avoid code duplication, which I believe can be solved by using a shared controller.

Comment: @WalterBrand it is hard to know if the answer is: use `ng-show` instead or not.

Comment: @DavinTryon true, the question isn't very clear

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a controller to this.

EDIT:
assuming that you want to avoid code duplication in both directives and do not want to use the scope in a service (where it doesn't belong)

EDIT2:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = function(){};
  $scope.hide = function(){};
});

app.directive('directive2', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'MyCtrl'
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
       ...
    }
  }
})

app.directive('directive1', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'MyCtrl'
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
       ...
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: you mean one controller for both directives?

Comment: I assume you do not want to duplicate the same code in both directories. And yes, I mean one controller for both directives.

Comment: hmm, never though of that. will try

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @EdChum the question was: what is the best solution for this. Since he mentions service but hesitates (because a service should not deal with the scope), I believe that using a controller is an appropriate answer. The person asking the questions considers it a useful option. So why do you think that it is not an answer to the question?

Comment: @WalterBrand I think your answer needs a bit more fleshing out, at the moment although it may be correct it appears to be like a simple comment, as you've added more reason in comments and now updated your answer it is clearer now. It may explain why others have downvoted it although why is rarely explained, I didn't downvote but your answer was automatically flagged for review because of it's length and content

Comment: @EdChum thanks for your clarification. Added a code example to make my point. But if that receives any downvotes, I will delete it.

Comment: @WalterBrand No worries, the comments are added by SO so sometimes it is not clear the reason behind the comments. Personally I prefer to comment as to why if I can but others may not.

Comment: this solution is not ok, because then the controller is global, and can be overwritten